# How to execute a Class method from decorator function

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, decorator, python-decorators

I have a class with a main dictionary `self.wardrobe`, which is being saved to a JSON file by the method: `self.save()`.

I am now trying to make a decorator which calls the `self.save()`, method after executing the decorated method.

Thanks in advance :)

Edit:

This is a try defining the decorator outside of the class (I also tried `@staticmethod` but it didn't work somehow):

```
def decorate_save(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        val = func(*args, **kwargs)
        self.save()
        return val
    return inner()
```

Second Edit:

this is the part of the class important for this problem:

```
class Wardrobe:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.filepath = filepath
        with open(self.filepath, 'r') as f:
            self.wardrobe = json.load(f)
        # self.wardobe is a dict

    def duplicate(self, index: int):
        item = self.wardrobe['all'][index]
        self.wardrobe['all'].append(item) # self.wardrobe['all'] is a list

    def save(self):
        with open(self.filepath, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(self.wardrobe, f, indent=4)
```

Summary: I want to create a decorator for the method `duplicate()`, which executes the method `save()` right after.

(of course I have other functions than `duplicate()`, which need to save afterwards too. thats why I dont just call `save()` in the method.)

Comment: a few code snippets could be helpful.

Comment: i added a snippet, i cant think of anything else be useful to answer the question

Comment: I assume your decorator is intended for an instance method. Either add `self` as the first parameter to `inner`, or use `args[0].save()`.

Comment: tried it, wont work, because args[0] is not self but the integer passed to my decorated func

Comment: @smyril please add the code where you decorate and call a method and get the issue

Comment: Couple of issues. 1) json file format expects all keys to be strings, you have integers 2) dictionaries (`self.wardrobe`) don't have an `append` method.

Comment: Im sorry, actually self.wardrobe is a dictionary containing a list by the key 'all' I just tried to make it simpler for y'all.

There are no integers in the dictionary/json the integer I used is just the index of the item to be duplicated. I'll edit my question to make more sense. 
@Tzane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When decorating a method `self` is the first argument passed to inner. You could do something like:

```py
import json

def decorate_save(method):
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        val = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.save()
        return val
    return inner

class Wardrobe:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.filepath = filepath
        with open(self.filepath, 'r') as f:
            self.wardrobe = json.load(f)
        # self.wardobe is a dict

    @decorate_save
    def duplicate(self, index: int):
        item = self.wardrobe['all'][index]
        self.wardrobe['all'].append(item) # self.wardrobe['all'] is a list

    def save(self):
        with open(self.filepath, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(self.wardrobe, f, indent=4)

w = Wardrobe('input_nogit.json')
w.duplicate(1)
```

Input json:

```
{
    "all": [
        "socks",
        "sandals"
    ]
}
```

Output json:

```
{
    "all": [
        "socks",
        "sandals",
        "sandals"
    ]
}
```

Comment: sadly this is not working since my decorated function has a parameter which is an index (therefore integer). Now the decorator calls save on the int and my IDE complains: "Type 'int' doesn't have expected attribute 'save'" and python just writes a None (null) to my file

Comment: @smyril Parameters shouldn't be an issue. You can see in the example `greetings` takes a parameter so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @smyril you **must** provide a [mcve]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I did

Comment: @smyril Updated my answer with your example code, hope it helps

Comment: @Tzane i don't know why it didn't work yesterday but i just tried it again and it works fine.
Thank you very much